# Javassist instrumenting field accesses

Tags: java, field, javassist

Does anyone know if there's any way to intercept field accesses on the accessed class with Javassits?

```
public class Original{
    public int field;
}

public class User {
    Original o;
        ...
    public int query(){
        return o.field;
    }
    public void set(){
        o.field=3;
    }
}
```

What I want is that whenever another class accesses the field from any original instance, it runs some extra code (e.g. `System.out.println("Reading field");`)

I know that extending the class javassist.expr.ExprEditor and implementing the method `void edit(FieldAccess fa)`, I can replace the field access for any other code that I want, but on the accessing class.

This requires to modify any class accessing that field. In our example the User class a replace all the read accesses by `System.out.println(...);XXX=o.field`, and all the write accesses by `System.out.println(...);o.field=XXX`

What I want to do is to convert a regular class instance into a proxy so any field access triggers a method execution. Is it feasible? Does it have any impact on possible subclasses?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is making all your proxy's fields private, and of course provide corresponding setters/getters, after that, you would implement a MethodHandler which will contain the method that you want to execute (ie. invoke) and you need to imeplement a MethodFilter in which you will designate which methods you want to intercept (in your case the getters/setters)

I think you're already familiar with javassist, so no code samples are needed i think, otherwise, i can edit this post to provide examples

I hope you get the idea ;)

Comment: I get the idea. I know how to add the getters and setters with the handler invocation and how to change the field definition. By now, no need of code. What I don't see clear is how other classes (already compiled) will replace their accesses to the field by calls to these getters/setters instead of trying to read a private attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry about the delay, it's these getters and setters that are going to be proxied, your client code won't have to change, and u'll handle interceptions in your MethodHandler

Comment: No problem, it's a long term development that I'm thinking about. By now just evaluating possibilities. I'm not really sure that I understood what you meant properly. I would really appreciate a code example (simple one). I edited the question to ease it. In your solution, you would create a proxy subclass or it would just modify the original one?

Comment: since you're having a direct access, your client code must change, i don't see how else you could do that, my idea was simply about decorating accessors (getters/setters) using a subclass proxy, i'm sorry i couldn't be of any help

Comment: That was what I was afraid of :(
Thanks for the help anyways